# Trying to use two "remote true" for separate Ajax calls in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am attempting to allow a user to make a comment and delete a comment all on the same page using Ajax calls. Currently a user can post a comment and delete a comment but when I put in remote true in both views neither will render without having to reload the page. If I take one remote true out then that means that one will automatically reload while the other does not. Any suggestions on how to enable both remote trues to work at the same time? This is my first time doing this.

Here is my first view where a user can post a comment

```
<%= form_for [@part, Comment.new], remote: true do |f|%>
        <div>
          <%= f.text_area :content %>
          <%= f.submit "Post Comment"%>
        </div>
        <%end%>
```

How a user can delete a comment

```
<%=link_to 'delete', part_comment_path(@part, comment), data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?"}, remote: true, method: :delete%>
```

and the create.js.erb

```
$('.comments').append("<%= j(render @comment) %>")
```

thanks to anyone who can explain how to fix this

UPDATE 
Here is my comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    part = Part.find(params[:part_id])
    @comment = part.comments.create(comment_params.merge(user: current_user))

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to @part}
      format.js{}
  end
end

  def destroy
    @part = Part.find(params[:part_id])
    @comment = @part.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to @part}
      format.js{}
    end
  end

private
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
  end
end
```

and here are my routes for comments

```
resources :parts do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

in case this helps out at all

Here are my logs as well

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments", :id=>"52", :part_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:part_id]):
    1: <li><%= comment.content%> by: <%= comment.user.first_name %> </li>
    2: <% if logged_in? %>
    3: <%=link_to 'delete', part_comment_path(@part, comment), remote: true, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?"}, method: :delete%>
    4: <%end%>
  app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_comments__comment_html_erb___3749430301288060826_70216407028000'
  app/views/comments/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_comments_create_js_erb___1584098095545825378_70216383980080'
```

This appears to be the problem....I do not understand how this is missing the part_id.

Screenshot of the error in my logs

[image]

_comment.html.erb view

```
<li><%= comment.content%> by: <%= comment.user.first_name %> </li>
<% if logged_in? %>
<%=link_to 'delete', part_comment_path(@part, comment), remote: true, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?"}, method: :delete%>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 def destroy
   @part = Part.find(params[:part_id])
   @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
   if @comment.destroy
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.js
     end
   end
 end
```

If it doesn't find the `part_id` then try this:

```
<%=link_to 'delete', part_comment_path(id: comment.id), remote: true, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?"}, method: :delete%>  


def destroy
   @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
   if @comment.destroy
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.js
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: I already have respond_to do |format| for both the create and destroy methods in my comments controller

Comment: Share the logs pls alongside the controller and routes.

Comment: How do you structure you views? Is `@part` available in your _comment.html.erb?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108977/discussion-between-dan-and-szilard-magyar).